# Deleting row value from Multiple point feature in different sub-folder using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have different month folders, each folder contain a shapefile called, For January folder Merged001.shp, For FEBRUARY Merged002.shp so on,

That shapefile having one field name 'Solar', and i am trying to delete specific  value from Solar field or we can say whichever value < 15 its will be deleted from Solar field (which is < 15.)

I have made a script to loop through all the month folder and read it the shapefile's Solar field and delete it < 15 value.

Below is my script and error massage

```
    import arcpy, os, calendar
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    topWorkspace = r'D:\Delete_Test'
    env.workspace = topWorkspace
    env.overwriteOutput = True

    months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} 
    for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
        baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
        if baseName in months: 
            monthNumber = months[baseName]
        arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

        shapeFiles = (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Merged_*.shp')[0])
        print shapeFiles

    with arcpy.UpdateCursor(shapeFiles, ["Solar"]) as cursor:
 for row in cursor:
    if row [0] < 17:
        cursor.deleteRow(row)
del row
```

error massage :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 19, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: Just want to verify your indentation is correct on your question: `rows =` line is 'outside' the `for folderPath` block?

Comment: i have to put folderpath there instead of ShapeFiles ?

Comment: I have updated the below line, but problem still persist                                                `with arcpy.UpdateCursor(shapeFiles, ["Solar"]) as cur:`
 `for row in cur:`
    `if row.Solar < 17:`
       `rows.deleteRow(row)`
`del row`

Comment: It is usually easier if you just update your question with any changes in formatting/code you've done.  Pay close attention to your indenting. Then other people have a better chance of understanding your problem.

Comment: I didn't update anything on source code, and my question remain same at the end, whatever i tried i mentioned in comment line

Comment: @RichardMorgan, As your suggestion, I updated my code and error massage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would check is your indentation.

```
for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
    baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
    if baseName in months: 
        monthNumber = months[baseName]
    arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

    shapeFiles = (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Merged_*.shp')[0])
    print shapeFiles

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(shapeFiles, "", "", "Solar")
```

The way this code reads is that you go through all the workspaces and assign the feature classes to the shapeFiles tuple.  You just then print the shapeFiles.

Since the `rows =` line is not indented, it is outside the loop.  It will only run against the last record in your loop.  This is probably not what you want.

Try:

```
for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
    baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
    if baseName in months: 
        monthNumber = months[baseName]
    arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

    shapeFiles = (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Merged_*.shp')[0])
    print shapeFiles

    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(shapeFiles, "", "", "Solar")
    for row in rows:
        if row.Solar < 17:
            rows.deleteRow(row)
    del row
    del rows
```

The next thing that looks odd to me is that you are asking the row for its value of Solar using `row.Solar`.  Typically, to get the value from the row, you use an index to read the tuple:

```
if row[0] < 17:
    rows.deleteRow(row)
```

The value of row[0] refers to the 'Solar' column since it's the first (and only) field listed.

Also, and this is just extra, when dealing with cursors, use the [arcpy.da module](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/what-is-the-data-access-module-.htm) instead.  They are much speedier.  The syntax is slightly different, so be careful:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapeFiles, "Solar") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] < 17:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

There may be other issues with your code, but if you are seeing the correct value of `shapeFiles` being printed out, you should be good.